# Retrieving a deleted folder with images

Tags: image, image-upload

**Problem background**

At the Insert Image page I accidentally removed a folder. I was trying to delete one image.

**Question**

Is it possible to retrieve this deleted data? If so how?

Comment: Do you make backups of your files? If so, go to the magento folder media/wysiwyg/ and restore it back.

Comment: No possible ,magento does  not take backup of image.

Comment: After rolling back the backup files, will it be required to make changes in the database?

Comment: If you fear that, re-upload from wysiwyg, should be a matter of minutes

Comment: How I feel now: http://nerdreactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Superman1.jpg

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in `\Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage::deleteDirectory` I think you are out of luck.

```
public function deleteDirectory($path)
{
    // prevent accidental root directory deleting
    $rootCmp = rtrim($this->getHelper()->getStorageRoot(), DS);
    $pathCmp = rtrim($path, DS);

    if ($rootCmp == $pathCmp) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Cannot delete root directory %s.', $path));
    }

    $io = new Varien_Io_File();

    if (!$io->rmdir($path, true)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('cms')->__('Cannot delete directory %s.', $path));
    }

    if (strpos($pathCmp, $rootCmp) === 0) {
        $io->rmdir($this->getThumbnailRoot() . DS . ltrim(substr($pathCmp, strlen($rootCmp)), '\\/'), true);
    }
}
```

You last chance (I didn't check) whether the button doesn't call `\Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_ImagesController::deleteFolderAction`

So back to the backup idea.